# $G/{C_G(M)}$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $M$ a nonabelian minimal normal subgroup of G and
$C = C_G(M)$. How can I show that $G/C$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup, which is isomorphic to $M$ ?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $M \cap C_G(M)=Z(M)=1$, because $M$ is nonabelian and minimal normal. Let $N/C_G(M)$ be a non-trivial minimal normal subgroup of $G/C_G(M)$.

Then $N \unlhd G$ and consider $M \cap N \unlhd G$. Since $M$ is minimal normal, $M \cap N=1$ or $M \cap N=M$. In the first case, $M$ and $N$ commute so, $N \subseteq C_G(M)$, thus $N=C_G(M)$, contradicting $N/C_G(M)$ being non-trivial. Hence $M \subseteq N$. But $N/C_G(M)$ is minimal normal, whence $MC_G(M)/C_G(M)=\overline{1}$, or $MC_G(M)/C_G(M)=N/C_G(M)$.

The first case gives $M \subseteq C_G(M)$, meaning $M$ is abelian, a contradiction. So $MC_G(M)=N$, and using the Second Isomorphism Theorem, this yields $N/C_G(M) \cong M/(M \cap C_G(M)) \cong M/Z(M) \cong M$ $\square$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.